# Is the relation $\{(x^4,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ a function that maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $ \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, functions

Is $\{(x^4,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ a function that maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $ \mathbb{R}$?

Since $x^4$ will make all the negative elements in $\mathbb{R}$ positive, does it map to $\mathbb{R}^+$ instead? However since $\mathbb{R}^+ \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ does it still map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $ \mathbb{R}$? Im so confused

Comment: Since the output is an ordered pair the range is $\mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}$ which is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The set you describe is not a function. Do you mean the function $x\mapsto x^4$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 but if it were in the range $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ it would be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range of a function just needs to be a set that includes all the function values.  You have defined a relation that has multiple cases of the same element in the first position with different elements in the second.  It is therefore not a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

If you define a function $f(x)=x^4$, that is a fine function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.  There is no requirement that the function values cover the range.  We define surjective functions as those that do have a value in the domain that maps to every element of the range.

If you try to define a function $f(x^4)=x$, that is not a function at all because $x^4=1$ will give pairs $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.  An input value is not mapped to a unique output value, which is required of a function.

Comment: No, the ordered pairs are not the "output". They are elements of the relation. A relation is a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: @h4ppyturt1e:  I had misread your definition and my answer was wrong.  I have updated it, but please unaccept it so I can delete it.  The other two answers are correct in their reading.

Answer (score 2):

A relation $f \subseteq X \times Y$ is called a function when

$$
\begin{align}
\text{(right-unique): }&\forall x \in X: \forall y \in Y: \forall z \in Y: ((x,y) \in f \land (x,z) \in f) \Rightarrow y = z\\
\text{(left-total): }&\forall x \in X: \exists y \in Y: (x,y)\in f
\end{align}
$$
The relation you showed is left-total but not right-unique if you choose the domain $X = \mathbb{R}_+$ and the codomain $Y = \mathbb{R}$ and therefore, it is not a function. Likewise, the relation is not left-total nor right-unique if you choose $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}$ and therefore, it is still not a function.

Answer (score 2):

A relation is a function over a set if, given any particular value in that set, that value appears as left-hand value in exactly one ordered pair.

In your relation, both $(16,2)$ and $(16,-2)$ appear, so the value $16$ appears as the left-side value in two different ordered pairs, which means this is not a function.